# How to add some space to row items in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a screen that contains a Row widget with 3 Column children. I want to add a space for the first children and another space for the second children. In general, I want a screen like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I try with these codes but not work correctly.

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          item(),
                          item(),
                          item(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          item(),
                          item(),
                          item(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          item(),
                          item(),
                          item(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
```

Can you help me?

Comment: That's strange, I've tried the code you provided and it ran perfectly. I just nested the Row widget in a Scaffold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you and I just modified it with some Container().

```
Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
              //////here you have to add SizedBox widget with different heights
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 50,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Output:[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a `SizedBox` to the children of the `Row`s, each with different `height`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `SizedBox` between the items. Like:

```
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      item(),
                      SizedBox(height:20),
                      item(),
                      SizedBox(height:20),
                      item(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I think that is simple, but works.
You can use a `Container` with margins in the items too.

If you want a more complex item, you can use `ListView.separated`.

```
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Center(child: Text("Index $index")),
      ),
)
```

Comment: I don't want to change space between items in Columns, I want to add space to the top of columns.

Comment: You can just add the SizedBox as first item in Column.